# A question about Fourier transform of a function defined by an integral

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, fourier-transform

I have the function:
$$ G_k(x)_=\frac{1}{(4\pi)^{k/2}\Gamma(k/2)}\int_0^\infty e^{-\pi|x|^2/\delta}e^{-\delta/4\pi}\delta^{-(n-k)/2}\,\frac{d\delta}{\delta}, $$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $k>0$. I know that $G_k\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and:
$$ \mathcal{F}(G_k)(\xi)=(1+4\pi^2|\xi|^2)^{-k/2},\quad\forall\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n,k>0,$$
i want to prove that:
$$ \mathcal{F}(G_{2k})(\xi/2\pi)=(2\pi)^k\mathcal{F}(G_{2k})(2\pi\xi),\quad\forall\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n,k>0.$$
I don't know how to go on. Any help would be appreciated.

---

$\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform: for all $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, we set:
$$\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)e^{-2\pi i x\cdot \xi}\,dx\quad\forall\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$

Comment: The third display contradicts the second display. Just plug in and you will see.

Comment: Do you think that my claim is false? See here [link](http://ccms.or.kr/data/pdfpaper/jcms24_2/24_2_267.pdf) at the end of  page 269. (There are only 5 pages)

Comment: The display on the bottom of page 269 is incorrect (the first equation is OK, the second is not). I think the author meant $\mathcal{F}[G_{2k}(2\pi x)](\xi)$ in place of $\mathcal{F}[G_{2k}](2\pi\xi)$. At any rate, on the top of page 270, $2\pi\xi$ should be $\xi/2\pi$ and $(2\pi)^k$ should be omitted in the first line, and then the next line is correct by Plancherel. Note also that the Fourier transform is defined differently in this paper than in your post. See the display below (2.1).

Comment: So on the top of page 270 i shouldn't have the factor $2\pi$?

Comment: Yes, the factor $(2\pi)^k$ should be deleted in the first line of the first display on page 270, and $2\pi\xi$ should be $\xi/2\pi$ in that line.

Comment: If i set: $$ G_{2k}^{(2\pi)}(x):=G_{2k}(2\pi x),\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n, $$ then, is true that; $$ \mathcal{F}(G_{2k}^{(2\pi)})(\xi)=(2\pi)^{-n}\mathcal{F}(G_{2k})(\xi/2\pi) =(2\pi)^{-n}(1+|\xi|^2)^{-k},\quad\forall\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n. $$ I think the author means this.

Comment: Yes, and this is what I wrote in my previous comments.